# Can the words "demonstrate intelligence" convey my initial meaning?

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-usage

I wrote the sentence as follows. In this sentence, I want to express that people can train the neural network by using the calculation of matrix (belonging to linear algebra). After training, the neural network will have the ability to predict or behave like humans, i.e. Artificial Intelligence.

> “The professor talked about the idea that numerical calculations of linear algebra could demonstrate intelligence.”

I want to ask that can “demonstrate intelligence” in this sentence convey my initial meaning? I think “demonstrate intelligence” may sound like a little strange in this sentence. If it is not suitable, what are other reasonable words to express my meaning? How about using “realize intelligence” or “realize artificial intelligence” or “demonstrate artificial intelligence” to replace “demonstrate intelligence”? Or how about using "numerical calculations of linear algebra in artificial intelligence could demonstrate intelligence"?

Comment: I don't think it's wrong per se.  Maybe not the best choice of verb. What about "reveal"? Or perhaps "could allow us to detect intelligence".

Comment: The sentence is grammatical but not true.

Answer (score 1):

"demonstrate intelligence" would not be **incorrect** here, but it would suggest a much larger result than a so-called neural network can provide. (the name is unfortunate because it is not in fact a close model of what a biological neural network does, but that was not as well understood when the name "neural network" was devised.  I would prefer to say something like

> The professor talked about the idea that numerical calculations using linear algebra could produce apparently intelligent results.

or

> The professor talked about the idea that numerical calculations using linear algebra could make selections similar to those a trained human would make.

Both of these are more precise on just what a trained neural network can in fact accomplish. "demonstrate intelligence" is a very broad and general claim. It suggests a wide range of behavior similar to that of a human. It suggests performing a much wider range of tasks than the kind of selection and classification that a neural network can provide.

All that said, purely as a matter of language, I would suggest "exhibit" as an alternative to "demonstrate".

In a comment, the OP suggests:

> The professor talked about the idea that numerical calculations using linear algebra could produce apparently intelligent results, such as human face detection, neural dialogue system, etc.

Here "human face detection" is a task that the network might accomplish, but "neural dialogue system" is a thing, not a task, so it does not fit the sentence well. A verb form comparable to detection  would be better, such as "maintenance" giving:

> The professor talked about the idea that numerical calculations using linear algebra could produce apparently intelligent results, such as human face detection, neural dialogue system maintenance, and similar tasks.

There are many other possibilities, of course.

Comment: Thank you very much! I am enlightened by your comment. I get a idea that it may be better and more clear to follow some intelligent instances. For example, “The professor talked about the idea that numerical calculations using linear algebra could produce apparently intelligent results, such as human face detection, neural dialogue system, etc.” May I ask that do you think the sentence in my example sounds better and more clear? If not, is there any word not suitable to be used in the sentence in my example?